# Creating xml elements in an existing xml file (Java) code didn't get error but the XML file unchanged after running

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to add child elements to an existing XML file. The XML file originally contain only the root element Item>. My code ateempts to create a child element Task0> It creates an element with the name of "task" + number of tasks already in the file. For example, if there's already 4 tasks in the file (up to Task3), the code will create Task4. Then the code creates four child elements of the task0> element.

Ignore the imports

```
class testXML {
public static int number = 0;
public static void main (String args[]) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("src/Store.xml");

        //create the task element
        Element Item = document.getDocumentElement();
        number = Item.getChildNodes().getLength();
        Element newTask = document.createElement("task" + (number));
        Item.appendChild(newTask);

        Node Task = document.getElementsByTagName("task" + number).item(0);
        //create all the child elements
        Element name = document.createElement("name");
        Element category = document.createElement("category");
        Element subject = document.createElement("subject");
        Element date = document.createElement("date");

        Task.appendChild(name);
        Task.appendChild(category);
        Task.appendChild(subject);
        Task.appendChild(date);                                 

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("src/Sotre.xml"));
        transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

        System.out.println("done");


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The console does print out "done", but when I check the xml file, nothing changed. So I wander why this happens. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Is the original XML file (`src/Store.xml`) unchanged because you're writing to `src/Sotre.xml` instead (note the misspelling of 'Store')?

Comment: yes, the xml file is called "Store"

Comment: Well if the XML file you're trying to update is called `Store.xml` and you're updating a file named `Sotre.xml` (see the line `StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("src/Sotre.xml"));`), is it any wonder why `Store.xml` isn't being updated?

Comment: oh wow I didn't realize that, thanks a lot